# Can chained `.then()`s return responses in a different order than order of `.then()`s?

Tags: javascript, callback

In the example below, would it be possible for the server response to `doSomethingOne`s request to come back before the server response to `doSomethingTwo`'s request?

```
$scope.pace = $interval (
    function() {

        // code

    }, 1000, 10

).then(postResult)
    .then(doSomethingOne)
        .then(doSomethingTwo);
```

Question being because, `doSomethingOne` is posting data to the db, and then `doSomethingTwo` is querying the db and returning some data, including data that `doSomethingOne` should have posted.

But the response to `doSomethingTwo`'s request doesn't include the most recent data posted by `doSomethingOne` (until the `$scope.pace` is run again from the beginning).

I don't have a strong understanding of callbacks (despite a lot of reading about them) so any advice would be very appreciated.

**Brief Clarification**

`doSomthingOne` does an `$http.post()` and `doSomethingTwo` does an `$http.get()`. No promises are used here.

Comment: It depends on what `doSomethingOne` does and what it returns.

Comment: You need to show the functions `doSomthingOne` and `doSomethingTwo`. But if `No promises are used here`   then `doSomethingTwo` is call immediately after  `doSomthingOne` , so both `post` and `get` happen nearly at the same time and because of that your `get` request could even reach the serve  before the `post`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

From your edit:

> doSomthingOne does an $http.post() and doSomethingTwo does an $http.get(). No promises are used here.

Well, `$http.post` [returns a promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) (sometimes called a "future" in the documentation), but if you're not using it, then nothing prevents `doSomethingTwo` from being called before the POST is completed. In fact, it's **very** likely to be called before the POST completes (long before).

You can probably fix the problem simply by returning the promise `$http.post` returns (or returning the promise created by your call on that promise, if you're using one). E.g.:

```
function doSomethingOne() {
    return $http.post(/*...args...*/);
}
```

or

```
function doSomethingOne() {
    return $http.post(/*...args...*/).then(/*...*/);
}
```

Details in the below.

**Original Answer** (still relevant):

It depends on what `doSomethingOne` does and what it returns. If `doSomethingOne` starts an asynchronous process but *doesn't* return a promise for that process, then `doSomethingTwo` can be called before that process is complete. If `doSomethingOne` does its work synchronously (unlikely given what you've said) or returns a promise for its asynchronous work, it will complete before `doSomethingTwo` is called because `doSomethingTwo` waits for that promise to be settled.

Here's an example where `doSomethingOne` doesn't return a promise for its async work, and so `doSomethingTwo` is likely to run before `doSomethingOne`'s async work completes:

```
// Simulate an asynchronous DB call
function dbCall(data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("Result for " + data);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 500));
  })
}
function start() {
  console.log("start called");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("start resolving");
      resolve();
    }, 0);
  })
}
function doSomethingOne() {
  // THIS IS PROBABLY WRONG
  console.log("doSomethingOne called");
  dbCall("one data").then(function(result) {
    console.log("doSometingOne's async is done");
  });
}
function doSomethingTwo() {
  console.log("doSomethingTwo called");
}
start().then(doSomethingOne).then(doSomethingTwo);
```

[Live copy on Babel's REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&code=%2F%2F%20Simulate%20an%20asynchronous%20DB%20call%0Afunction%20dbCall(data)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(function(resolve)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22Result%20for%20%22%20%2B%20data)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20Math.floor(Math.random()%20*%20500))%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0Afunction%20start()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22start%20called%22)%3B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22start%20resolving%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0Afunction%20doSomethingOne()%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20THIS%20IS%20PROBABLY%20WRONG%0A%20%20console.log(%22doSomethingOne%20called%22)%3B%0A%20%20dbCall(%22one%20data%22).then(function(result)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22doSometingOne's%20async%20is%20done%22)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20doSomethingTwo()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22doSomethingTwo%20called%22)%3B%0A%7D%0Astart().then(doSomethingOne).then(doSomethingTwo)%3B)

**That's probably wrong.** Instead, you want `doSomethingOne` to return a promise from its async work; it can do that by just returning the result of its call on `dbCall(...).then`:

```
// Simulate an asynchronous DB call
function dbCall(data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("Result for " + data);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 500));
  })
}
function start() {
  console.log("start called");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("start resolving");
      resolve();
    }, 0);
  })
}
function doSomethingOne() {
  console.log("doSomethingOne called");
  return dbCall("one data").then(function(result) {
//^^^^^^^------------------------------------------- change is here
    console.log("doSometingOne's async is done");
  });
}
function doSomethingTwo() {
  console.log("doSomethingTwo called");
}
start().then(doSomethingOne).then(doSomethingTwo);
```

[Live copy on Babel's REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&code=%2F%2F%20Simulate%20an%20asynchronous%20DB%20call%0Afunction%20dbCall(data)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(function(resolve)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22Result%20for%20%22%20%2B%20data)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20Math.floor(Math.random()%20*%20500))%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0Afunction%20start()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22start%20called%22)%3B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22start%20resolving%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0Afunction%20doSomethingOne()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22doSomethingOne%20called%22)%3B%0A%20%20return%20dbCall(%22one%20data%22).then(function(result)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22doSometingOne's%20async%20is%20done%22)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20doSomethingTwo()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22doSomethingTwo%20called%22)%3B%0A%7D%0Astart().then(doSomethingOne).then(doSomethingTwo)%3B)

Comment: I'm trying to understand this (the last example). What is the purpose of incorporating the `setTimeout` into the dbCall?

Comment: @pandaman: To make it asynchronous, like your `$http.post` is.

Comment: So by adding the `return` at the end of the function, then the next `.then()` won't fire until the function completes. It also looks like it works with just a `return;` followed by a semicolon which returns nothing... if I understand correctly.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with *whether* the function returns something, it has to do with *what* the function returns. Just `return;` wouldn't do it. You need to return the promise that you get from `$http.post`. `then` always returns a promise; if you have `var p2 = p1.then(f);`, `p2` will be a promise. When `p1` is resolved, `f` is called. If `f` returns a promise, `p2` waits for that promise before being settled. If your function returns anything else (or nothing), `p2` is settled immediately.